# How to parse time from date string retrieved from Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, date

I'm getting these times from Facebook events. E.g: start_time and it's a string like this:

> 2013-12-21T18:30:00+0100

Now I just want the time, like:

> 18.30

I tried to do it with this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
                Date formatted = null;
                try {
                    formatted = formatter.parse(p.getStart_time());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String formattedString = formatted.toString();
                txtStart_time.setText(""+formattedString);
```

`p.getStart_time()` is a String that gives me the date like I said before.

If I do this method, I get an error:

> Unparseable date.

Does anybody know a work around?

Comment: Well obviously this format `2013-12-21T18:30:00+0100` does not match yours. What did you expect?

Comment: What time zone do you want the extracted time? The same +01:00 offset?

Answer (score 11):

You need two formats: one to parse the date and one to format it

```
String startTime = "2013-12-21T18:30:00+0100";
SimpleDateFormat incomingFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date date = incomingFormat.parse(startTime);

SimpleDateFormat outgoingFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy", java.util.Locale.getDefault());

System.out.println(outgoingFormat.format(date));
```

prints

```
 Saturday, 21 December 2013
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting these times from Facebook events. E.g: start_time and it's
> a string like this:
>
> 2013-12-21T18:30:00+0100
>
> Now I just want the time, like:
>
> 18.30

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern date-time API:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse(
    "2013-12-21T18:30:00+0100", 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
).toLocalTime()
```

**Description:** Your date-time string has a timezone offset of `+01:00` hours. `java.time` API provides you with `OffsetDateTime` to contain the information of date-time units along with the timezone offset. Using the applicable `DateTimeFormatter`, parse the string into an `OffsetDateTime` and then get the `LocalTime` part of this date-time using [`OffsetDateTime#toLocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toLocalTime--).

**Demo using `java.time` API**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(
            "2013-12-21T18:30:00+0100", 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ).toLocalTime());
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
18:30
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/jd8J45)

**Note:** You can use `y` instead of `u` here but [I prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) `u` to `y`.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### A note about the legacy API:

The question and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720477/10819573) use `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` which was the correct thing to do in 2013. In Mar 2014, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Since then, it is highly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` as parsing format instead of `EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

### Substring

If all you want is literally the time component lifted from that string, call the [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method on the String class…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

String dateTimeStringFromFacebook = "2013-12-21T18:30:00+0100";

// Extract a substring.
String timeSubstring = dateTimeStringFromFacebook.substring( 11, 19 );
```

### DateTime Object

If you want the time converted to a particular time zone, convert the string to a date-time object. Use a formatter to express just the time component.

Here is some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library. Avoid the notoriously bad java.util.Date/Calendar classes. Use either Joda-Time or the new java.time.* JSR 310 classes bundled with Java 8.

```
// From String to DateTime object.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( dateTimeStringFromFacebook, DateTimeZone.UTC );

// From DateTime object to String
// Extract just the hours, minutes, seconds.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String timeFragment_Paris = formatter.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) ).print( dateTime );
String timeFragment_Kolkata = formatter.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ).print( dateTime ); // Formerly known as Calcutta, India.
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeStringFromFacebook: "  + dateTimeStringFromFacebook );
System.out.println( "timeSubstring: " + timeSubstring );
System.out.println( "dateTime: "  + dateTime );
System.out.println( "timeFragment_Paris: "  + timeFragment_Paris );
System.out.println( "timeFragment_Kolkata: " + timeFragment_Kolkata + " (Note the 00:30 difference due to +05:30 offset)");
```

When run…

```
dateTimeStringFromFacebook: 2013-12-21T18:30:00+0100
timeSubstring: 18:30:00
dateTime: 2013-12-21T17:30:00.000Z
timeFragment_Paris: 18:30:00
timeFragment_Kolkata: 23:00:00 (Note the 00:30 difference due to +05:30 offset)
```

### Think Time Zone

Your question fails to address the question of time zone. Make a habit of always thinking about time zone whenever working with date-time values. If you mean the same time zone, say so explicitly. If you mean the default time zone of the Java environment, say so. If you mean [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)… well, you get the idea.

Comment: This is a very good alternative solution.